# Derive the exact/perfect differential

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a "simple" question, but I dont know the answer :):
How do I come from:

$\frac{dx}{dt} = f(x,t)$

to:

$df = [\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}] dx + [\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}] dt $

Comment: use the chain rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat x and t as functions of some third variable, u, say.  Then, by the chain rule, as Alex S said, $\frac{df}{du}= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{du}+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\frac{dt}{du}$. Changing to "differential form", $df= \frac{df}{du}du= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{du}du+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\frac{dt}{du}du= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}dt$